# Завершение дочерних потоков при завершении родительского

Tags: асинхронность, java, многопоточность

Здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема - требуется завершать дочерние потоки, если прерывается поток, который их породил. Родительский поток живет пока работают дочернее, используя `join()`. Дочерние потоки используют в `run()` - `while (!Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted)`, то есть фактически бесконечные. Задача - прерывать дочерние потоки при прерывании родительского, при этом не объявляя дочерние потоки как демоны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда я сталкивался с подобной задачей я решал ее так:

В дочернем потоке было булевское поле **running** со стандартными get и set методами, значение которого периодически проверялось. Когда родительский поток заканчивал работу, он вызывал метод **setRunning(false)**. При очередной проверке, дочерний поток, увидев, что **running == false**, выходил из бесконечного цикла и заканчивал работу.

Добавил пример кода дочернего потока.

```
public class A extends Thread{
    private boolean running;
    public A(){
        running = true;
    }
    public synchronized void setRunning(boolean r){
        running = r;
    }
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.currentThread.isInteruped())
            if(!running)
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня так не проканает, тк родительский поток просто висит и дожидается окончания дочерних потоков. то есть в нем все так: childThread.start(); childThread.join() и нужно сделать так чтобы по прерывании потока допустим из консоли завершались и порожденные

Comment: То есть ты запускаешь в родительском потоке дочерний, говоришь родительскому ждать, пока завершится дочерний, но если родительскому ждать надоело и он завершается, то тебе надо завершить и дочерние. Так?

Comment: Да

Comment: Но ведь родительский поток не сам по себе завершится. Его завершит что-то извне. Разве это что-то извне не может получить ссылку на дочерний поток у родительского потока, чтобы вызвать у дочернего setRunning(false)?

Comment: в идеале его завершает ctrl+c в консоли, он просто инрерапится.
я вот думаю сработает ли отлов InterruptedException в родителе и в catch - интерапить дочерние

Comment: Я думаю, что по ctrl+c ты просто убьешь виртуальную машину Java и там уже будет нечего завершать или отлавливать...

Comment: Ну тем самым я убью не VM как таковую а процесс в VM,ну по идее и все потоки в этом процессе должны прекратиться. Как то не задумался об этом с такой позиции :) Хм, дурака свалял...

Comment: @Vladimir конечно, именно так и можно сделать. В документации к Thread.join() указано, что метод выкидывает исключение, если текущий поток прерывают. А ну если вариант с тотальным убийством проканывает, то ок :)

Answer (score 2):

вам нужен вариант реализации шаблона [Observer](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Наблюдатель_(шаблон_проектирования)) (вариант Б в чистом виде)
(вариант А немножко скован тем что обьект потока создается внутри метода, поэтому добавлен Runnable в качестве параметра. можно сделать и с помощью generic, тогда ваш класс MainThread будет более универсален)

```
class MainThread extends Thread
{
   private final Set < Thread > children = null;

   // variant A
   public Thread createChild ( final Runnable runnable )
   {
      final Thread t = new Thread ( runnable );

      // optional
      // t.start ();

      children.add ( t );

      return t;

   }

   @Override
   public void interrupt ()
   {
      removeAll ();

      super.interrupt ();
   }

   // variant B
   protected void add ( final Thread child )
   {
      if ( ( null != child ) && !children.contains ( child ) )
      {
         children.add ( child );
         child.start ();
      }
   }

   protected void remove ( final Thread child )
   {
      if ( children.contains ( child ) )
      {
         children.remove ( child );
         child.interrupt ();
      }
   }

   protected void removeAll ()
   {
      final Iterator < Thread > iterator = children.iterator ();
      while ( iterator.hasNext () )
      {
         iterator.next ().interrupt ();
      }
   }
}

class ChildThread extends Thread
{
   public ChildThread ( final MainThread parent )
   {
      parent.add ( this );
   }

   public void interrupt()
   {
       if (isRunning)    
       {
           isRunning = false;    
       }
   }

   public void run()
   {
       if (!isRunning)    
       {
           super.interrupt();
           return;    
       }

       // полезный код... если ChildThread и runImpl сделать абстрактными 
       // то получится еще и красиво :)
       runImpl();
   }
}
```

**UP: согласно пожеланиям публики убрал грубый interrupt :D**

Comment: Согласен, что такой вариант тоже возможен и иногда даже эффективнее, но отличие моего варианта в том, что поток не прерывается в непредсказуемый для дочернего потока момент, а корректно завершается так, как этого захочет программист. Мой способ просто выводит поток из бесконечного цикла, после которого он может до завершения успеть выдать какой-нибудь результат.

Comment: Чего то я не пойму - что при грубом прерывании родительского потока(допустим Ctrl+C c консоли) у него будет вызван его interrupt() ? Разве так ? По-моему join() выбросит InterruptedException и в catch уже можно будет интерапить родителя и дочерние. Вроде так. Поправьте если нет

Comment: 2 @Sasha121 ничего вам не напоминает ?:) зачем углублятся в ненужные детали. пытаясь решить проблему которую уже решили.

Comment: 2 @jmu - вопрос тот же - каким образом у меня вызовется interrupt если я просто убиваю процесс в JVM ?

Comment: убить процесс JVM это тоже что вытянуть шнур с розетки. естественно что в JVM ничего вызвано не будет.   
обрисуйте детальнее вашу задачу? непонятно зачем вам останавливать JVM таким грубым методом

Comment: Приложение консольное, нет никаких способов прервать его. Мне также посоветовали вешать на JVM хук

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону [CyclicBarrier](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

Comment: При чем тут CyclicBarrier ? У меня дочерние потоки бесконечные и не достигают никогда никаких логических барьеров. я просто хочу *правильно* прекращать работу программы(потоков)